# read csv and write binary

Tags: java, csv, binary

I have a problem with writting this program

I need to read a csv file and write it to binary then read it again. I has to be written in this way:

```
Field name Data type
Name First Text
Name Last Text
Birth Day Whole number
Birth Month Whole number
Birth Year 4-digit year
Weight Whole number
Height Number with decimal part
```

I now how to read csv and binary, but how to do this is a mistery to me.

What toubles me the most is that in this csv first line is just strings and then coninues name lastname and so on

```
namefirst namelast birthday birthmonth birthyear weight height

Starlin Castro 243199019072.8
Madison Bumgarner 18198921576.0
Jason Heyward 98198924077.3
Ruben Tejada 2710198916071.2
Jenrry Mejia 1110198916072.5
Mike Stanton 811198923577.9
Dayan Viciedo 103198924071.1
Chris Sale 303198917077.2
Freddie Freeman 129198922577.7
Clayton Kershaw 193198822575.4
Travis Snider 22198823572.0
Elvis Andrus 268198820072.0
Trevor Cahill 13198822076.0
Rick Porcello 2712198820077.0
Brett Anderson 12198823576.5
Fernando Martinez 1010198820073.0
Jhoulys Chacin 71198821575.2
Chris Tillman 154198820077.8
Neftali Feliz 25198821575.5
Craig Kimbrel 285198820571.6
```

Can you help me?

this is my code till now

I can read it line by line but how to continue now?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

 try
 {

                //csv file containing data
    String strFile = "BaseballNames1.csv";

                //create BufferedReader to read csv file
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader( new FileReader(strFile));
    String strLine = "";
    StringTokenizer st = null;
    int lineNumber = 0;
    int tokenNumber = 0;

                //read comma separated file line by line
    while( (strLine = br.readLine()) != null)
    {
       lineNumber++;

                        //break comma separated line using ","
       st = new StringTokenizer(strLine, ",");

       while(st.hasMoreTokens())
       {
                                //display csv values
          tokenNumber++;
                      /*                                                      

          String name = dis.readUTF();
          String lastName = dis.readUTF();
          int bDay = dis.readInt();
          int bMonth = dis.readInt();
          int bYear = dis.readInt();
          int weight = dis.readInt();
          double height = dis.readDouble();         */          



             System.out.println("tokel line:"+st.nextToken());  




       }

                        //reset token number
       tokenNumber = 0;

    }


 }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
       System.out.println("Exception while reading csv file: " + e);                  
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see commas in your input so breaking it on commas should probably be changed to breaking a line on spaces instead. I also see only one large float number where the heading line has five numbers specified. So generally you're going to need to clarify what's going in and what needs to come out.

Tell me this isn't homework.

Comment: Yes it is :D There is no commas because I copied formatted output, I just need and idea how to continue to binary. That in heading is form the assignment so I do not understand it either... The pint is that I need to take the values form the csv also white spaces and put it in binary file

Comment: @mehnihma Sorry I couldn't help earlier. What I'm seeing now is that the number 243199019072.8 probably means, 24th of 3rd month of 1990 190lbs 72.8" (not sure though) and EG 811198923577.9 is 8/11/1989 235lbs 77.9"? It would probably help in getting a final answer on this if you tried again to paste in the input with the delimiter intact.